# why my selection sort in typescript not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, sorting, selection-sort

I learn a simple selection sort algoritm and try using from javascript/typescript.

**and this my selection.sort algorithm in SelectionSort class**

```
export default class SelectionSort {
  private dataForSmallestToBiggest: number[];
  private dataForBiggestToSmallest: number[];
  public startData: number[];
  private biggestIndex: number = 0;
  private biggest: number = 0;
  private smallestIndex: number = 0;
  private smallest: number = 0;
  public iterationSmallestToBiggest: number = 0;
  public iterationBiggestToSmallest: number = 0;

  constructor(data: number[]) {
    // initiate for array smallest to biggest
    this.dataForSmallestToBiggest = data;
    // initiate for array biggest to smallest
    this.dataForBiggestToSmallest = data;
    // initiate for start data
    this.startData = data;
  }

  // set biggest data
  private setBiggest() {
    // initiate biggest data
    this.biggest = this.dataForBiggestToSmallest[0];
    //initiate biggest index data
    this.biggestIndex = 0;
    // looping for searching biggest index and biggest value from array
    this.dataForBiggestToSmallest.forEach((val, index) => {
      // if biggest found
      if (val > this.biggest) {
        // change biggest value
        this.biggest = val;
        // change biggest index
        this.biggestIndex = index;
      }
      // increase how many iteration for this looping
      this.iterationBiggestToSmallest++;
    });
  }

  // searching smallest data
  private setSmallest() {
    // initiate smallest data
    this.smallest = this.dataForSmallestToBiggest[0];
    //initiate smallest index data
    this.smallestIndex = 0;
    // looping for searching smallest index and smallest value from array
    this.dataForSmallestToBiggest.forEach((val, index) => {
      // if smallest found
      if (val < this.smallest) {
        // change the smallest value
        this.smallest = val;
        // change the smallest index
        this.smallestIndex = index;
      }
      // increase how many iteration for this looping
      this.iterationSmallestToBiggest++;
    });
  }
  // sorting from smallest to biggest
  public smallestToBiggest() {
    // initiate result variable
    let result: number[] = [];

    while (this.dataForSmallestToBiggest.length > 0) {
      //  change smallest value and smallest index
      this.setSmallest();
      // add result from smallest data;
      result.push(this.smallest);

      // remove array  by smallest inex
      this.dataForSmallestToBiggest.splice(this.smallestIndex, 1);
      // increase how many sorting smallest to biggest sort
      this.iterationSmallestToBiggest++;
    }
    return result;
  }

  // sorting from biggest to smallest
  public biggestToSmallest() {
    // initiate result variable
    let result: number[] = [];
    while (this.dataForBiggestToSmallest.length > 0) {
      //  change biggest value and biggest index
      this.setBiggest();

      // add result
      result.push(this.biggest);
      // remove array  by biggest inex
      this.dataForBiggestToSmallest.splice(this.biggestIndex, 1);
      // increase how many sorting smallest to biggest sort
      this.iterationBiggestToSmallest++;
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

if i call biggestTosmallest only or smallestToBiggest only this algorithm work

**i using biggest to smallest only**

```
import SelectionSort from "./SelectionSort.js";

let selection = new SelectionSort([1, 5, 6, 3, 2, 7, 10, 3, 56, 18, 784, 83]);

let biggestToSmallest = selection.biggestToSmallest();
console.log(
  `biggest to smallest  data : ${selection.startData} iteration : ${selection.iterationBiggestToSmallest} , result :`
);
console.log(biggestToSmallest);
```

[biggest to smallest work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nO7P.png)

**i using smallest to biggest only**

```
import SelectionSort from "./SelectionSort.js";

let selection = new SelectionSort([1, 5, 6, 3, 2, 7, 10, 3, 56, 18, 784, 83]);

let smallestToBiggest = selection.smallestToBiggest();
console.log(
  `smallest to biggest  data : ${selection.startData} iteration : ${selection.iterationSmallestToBiggest} , result :`
);
console.log(smallestToBiggest);
```

[smallest to biggest work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcVOF.png)

**But If i using biggest to smallest and smallest to biggest**

```
import SelectionSort from "./SelectionSort.js";

let selection = new SelectionSort([1, 5, 6, 3, 2, 7, 10, 3, 56, 18, 784, 83]);

let biggestToSmallest = selection.biggestToSmallest();
console.log(
  `biggest to smallest  data : ${selection.startData} iteration : ${selection.iterationBiggestToSmallest} , result :`
);
console.log(biggestToSmallest);

let smallestToBiggest = selection.smallestToBiggest();
console.log(
  `smallest to biggest  data : ${selection.startData} iteration : ${selection.iterationSmallestToBiggest} , result :`
);
console.log(smallestToBiggest);
```

[biggest to smallest only work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMuxI.png)

biggest to smallest only work, and smallest to biggest not work. startData property is erased too.

what wrong in my code?
and why only biggest to smallest work?

Comment: I think you can fix it by doing `this.dataForSmallestToBiggest = [...data];` and `this.dataForBiggestToSmallest = [...data];`

Answer (score 0):

As Carsten pointed out in his comment the problem is that even though you defined three variables:

```
// initiate for array smallest to biggest
dataForSmallestToBiggest = data;
// initiate for array biggest to smallest
this.dataForBiggestToSmallest = data;
// initiate for start data
this.startData = data;
```

They all use the same backing array **data**, so any modifications done to one of the three will be reflected in the others. Given that you apply `splice` to the array after `biggestToSmallest()` the variables `startData` and `dataForSmallestToBiggest` represent an empty array, that's why when you try to print `startData` you don't get any output.

So you can copy the `data` array on initialization like this:

```
// initiate for array smallest to biggest
dataForSmallestToBiggest = [...data];
// initiate for array biggest to smallest
this.dataForBiggestToSmallest = [...data];
// initiate for start data
this.startData = data;
```

So now the three variables will have the same data but point to different arrays.